# The Fixed-point theorem predicts the existence of quines.

Tags: logic, computability

From Odifreddi's "Classical Recursion Theory", Vol 1., page 165.

> The Fixed-Point Theorem can be used directly to find programs exhibiting self-referential features. E.g., by considering $f$ recursive such that $\varphi_{f(e)}(x) = e$ we get an index $e$ such that $\varphi_e(x) = e$ which can be interpreted as the code of a program printing itself.

Here is the statement of the theorem:

> **Fixed-point theorem**
>
> Given a recursive function $f$ there is an $e$ such that $\varphi_e \simeq \varphi_{f(e)}$, i.e. $e$ and $f(e)$ compute the same function.

To me it seems that the outlined procedure here is:

1. pick a recursive $f$ such that $\varphi_{f(e)}(x) = e$
2. take the $e'$ of the recursion theorem such that $\varphi_{e'} \simeq \varphi_{f(e')}$
3. we get $\varphi_{e'}(x) = e'$, i.e. a quine

Why such an $f$ exist? Note that $f$ must be recursive.

**Related but with other nuances**

[Does the recursion theorem give quines?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219021/does-the-recursion-theorem-give-quines/219040#219040)

[On the existence of an injective recursive function such that all its values are also its indexes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577399/on-the-existence-of-an-injective-recursive-function-such-that-all-its-values-are)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\psi$ be a recursive function (no need for partial recursive, because is just the projection function) such that: $\psi(x,y) = x$.

By the parameter theorem (S-m-n theorem), there exist a recursive function $f$ such that:

$$\phi_ {f(x)}(y) = \psi(x,y) = x.$$

As $f$ is recursive, by the fix-point theorem, it has a fix-point $e$, i.e. $\phi_{f(e)} = \phi_e$.

Then:

$$ \phi_e(y) = \psi(e,y) = e.$$

I think he is assuming this reasoning for the existence of $f$. Note that it don't matter witch constant you choose for $x$ before using the fix-point theorem (i.e. making $x=e$ we get $\phi_{f(e)}(x) = e$, the before-using-fix-point-theorem part on the Odifreddi text).